# How to get multi-language table data?

Tags: php, opencart

I am using `opencart 2.3.0.2`. I am trying to get multiple language data from data table. But output result not showing `value` and `title` properly.

`productmark` Table

```
title  value  language_id  product_id
 1st    2nd       1           42
 3st    4nd       2           42
```

`productmark` model

```
    public function getmarks($product_id) {

          $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "productmark WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
          return $query->rows;

    }

   public function getmarksdata($product_id,$language_id) {

          $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "productmark WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND language_id='".$language_id."'");
          return $query->rows;

    }
```

`productmark` controller

```
if (isset($this->request->post['productmark'])) {
            $productmarks = $this->request->post['productmark'];
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
            $productmarks = $this->model_productmark->getmarks($this->request->get['product_id']);
        } else {
            $productmarks = array();
        }

        $data['productmarks'] = array();        

        foreach ($productmarks as $key=> $productmark) {   
                foreach ($data['languages'] as $language){

                $productmarks_data = $this->model_productmark->getmarksdata($this->request->get['product_id'],$language['language_id']);

                $data['productmarks'][$key][$language['language_id']] = array(
                    'title' => $productmarks_data['title'],
                    'value' => $productmarks_data['value'],

                ); 

            }

          }
```

`productmark` template

```
<?php $productmark_row = 0; ?>
      <?php foreach ($productmarks as $productmark) { ?>
              <?php foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
                       <input type="text" name="productmark[<?php echo $productmark_row; ?>][<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>][title]" value="<?php echo $productmark[$language['language_id']]['title']; ?>" placeholder="Title" class="form-control" />
                <?php }?>
                <?php foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
                       <input type="text" name="productmark[<?php echo $productmark_row; ?>][<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>][value]" value="<?php echo $productmark[$language['language_id']]['value']; ?>" placeholder="Value" class="form-control" />
                 <?php }?>
 <?php $productmark_row++; ?>
```

Comment: Can you specify 'result not working/showing value and title properly ' a bit more? There is no result, or there is a wrong result or...?

Comment: I think problem is on controller file.

Comment: You are not supplying enough information.